# Download remote file straight to client?

Tags: php, download

I need download remote file straight to client. After some googling, I found this script in the php manual but its resume capability does not work. This script uses `Http_Range` to generate  a resumable download link. Is there any other method to do this? Of course, it would be by using `cUrl` but I need download remote file straight to client. How can i resolve this problem?

```
<?php          
$url="http://dl.remote-domain.com/files/file.mp4";
dl_file_resumable($url);

function dl_file_resumable($file, $is_resume=TRUE)
{


    //Gather relevent info about file
    $size = remotefilesize($file);
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($file);

    //workaround for IE filename bug with multiple periods / multiple dots in filename
    //that adds square brackets to filename - eg. setup.abc.exe becomes setup[1].abc.exe
    $filename = (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE')) ?
                  preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $fileinfo['basename'], substr_count($fileinfo

['basename'], '.') - 1) :
                  $fileinfo['basename'];

    $file_extension = strtolower($path_info['extension']);

    //This will set the Content-Type to the appropriate setting for the file
    switch($file_extension)
    {
        case 'exe': $ctype='application/octet-stream'; break;
        case 'zip': $ctype='application/zip'; break;
        case 'mp3': $ctype='audio/mpeg'; break;
        case 'mpg': $ctype='video/mpeg'; break;
        case 'avi': $ctype='video/x-msvideo'; break;
        default:    $ctype='application/force-download';
    }

    //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
    if($is_resume && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);

        if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
        {
            //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only 

serve the first range
            //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
            list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $range = '';
    }

    //figure out download piece from range (if set)
    list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

    //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
    //also check for invalid ranges.
    $seek_end = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($size - 1));
    $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs

(intval($seek_start)),0);

    //add headers if resumable
    if ($is_resume)
    {
        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        }

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$size);
    }

    //headers for IE Bugs (is this necessary?)
    //header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");   
    //header("Pragma: public");

    header('Content-Type: ' . $ctype);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));

    //open the file
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
    //seek to start of missing part
    fseek($fp, $seek_start);

    //start buffered download
    while(!feof($fp))
    {
        //reset time limit for big files
        set_time_limit(0);
        print(fread($fp, 1024*8));
        flush();
        ob_flush();
    }

    fclose($fp);
    exit;
}

function remotefilesize($url, $user = "", $pw = "")
{
    ob_start();
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

    if(!empty($user) && !empty($pw))
    {
        $headers = array('Authorization: Basic ' .  base64_encode("$user:$pw"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    $ok = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $head = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $regex = '/Content-Length:\s([0-9].+?)\s/';
    $count = preg_match($regex, $head, $matches);

    return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : "unknown";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem with current script ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just push file to user, follow these steps:

1. Start output buffering.
2. Read the file content as-is to buffer.
3. Set response header based on the mime type (as in the code you posted.)
4. Flush the output buffer.

The user will be prompted to save the file if the mime type is not renderable as per browser standards, otherwise the content will be displayed to them.
If you want to force the user to download and not render the content add the header `Content-disposition:attachment;filename=name.extension`, the part after the semicolon is optional.

Comment: I Know what is ur meaning, and in above code try to do this. Do u have any sample code? thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150692/output-buffering-for-php-file-download